# Error [object Text] al intentar poner valor en un input type text

Tags: javascript, dom

Una duda tal vez básica, que pensaba que sabria resolver y me estoy volviendo loco:

Quiero recuperar un texto que un div contiene en su interior, guardarlo en una variable y meterlo como valor en un input type text.

Cuando intento hacer esto, el texto que me aparece dentro del input type text es: [object Text].

```
function editaCmnt(e){
    var elemento = e.target;
    elementoHijo = elemento.previousSibling;

    //Aquí recupera el div que contiene texto en su interior
    divCmts = elementoHijo.previousSibling;

    //Aquí recupera el texto
    comentario = divCmts.firstChild;

    divCmts.style.display = "none";

    //Se crea el input
    inputAñadido = document.createElement("input");

    //Se añade como valor, el texto recuperado de dentro del div
    inputAñadido.setAttribute("value", comentario)

    //Se muestra el input (en teoria con el valor "comentario")
    elemento.before(inputAñadido);
}
```

El texto que quiero recuperar lo contiene $registro['Comentario']:

```
"<div class='contComentarios'>
        <div class='creadorFecha'>
            <div> Creado por: <strong>". $registro2['Nombre'] ."</strong></div>
            <div>". $registro['Fecha'] ."</div>
        </div>

        <div class='comentario'>". $registro['Comentario'] ."</div>

    <div class='modificaCmnt'>
        Editar
    </div>

    <div id=".$registro['Tema']." class='borrarTema borraCmnt'>
        <div id=". $registro['IdComentario'] ." class='borraCmnt' value='Borrar comentario'>Borrar comentario</div>
    </div>

</div>";
```

Comment: ¿Podrías editar tu pregunta y añadir la estructura HTML que estás utilizando?

Comment: A que te refieres? La estructura es muy extensa. No podría ponerlo todo

Comment: @enxaneta acabo de modificar la respuesta para que veas todo el código

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//Aquí recupera el texto
    comentario = divCmts.firstChild;
```

Aquí estás obteniendo el elemento completo, asumiendo como dice tu pregunta que es un div con texto necesitas acceder a la propiedad del innerHTML para obtener el texto que contiene:

```
//Aquí recupera el texto
    comentario = divCmts.firstChild.innerHTML;
```

---

El problema de usar innerHTML es que incluye TODO lo que esté dentro de tu elemento, por ejemplo si tu `<div>` tiene anidado un `<input>` este aparecerá dentro del `innerHTML`. Puedes usar la propiedad `.innerText` pero esta solo sirve en elementos de contenido de bloque (tags que tienes que abrir y cerrar como `<div>`, `<button>`, `<span>`, etc)

Comment: Nada, me aparece como un undefined. He añadido la pregunta para que veas desde donde recojo el texto.

Comment: Ya está solucionado, he hecho innerHTML al elementoHijo en vez de a divCmts.firstChild. Gracias por tu ayuda @Killbunny!